# Usage of に in the following sentence

Tags: particle-に

There are two sentences using に following 人情 that are confusing to me (both from Wanikani).

> 人情の温かさに　生かされています。(I survive on the warmth of humanity)

and

> コウイチ様は　人情味に　あふれている　すばらしいお方　ですが、ビエト様は　ひとかけらの人情　もない　ごく　悪ヤクザ　です。(Koichi-sama is such a wonderful person with deep empathy, but Viet is such a devilish yakuza with not one atom of humanity.)

My guess is either indication or purpose (but 人情/人情の温かさ are not verbs), or indication of location (not sure if abstract location like 'humanity' is possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first に is a marker for the "doer" of a passive verb. 生かされる is the passive form of the transitive verb 生かす ("to keep someone alive").

> 人情の温かさ**に**生かされています。
> I am kept alive **by** the warmth of humanity.

The second に is "(filled) with" or "(full) of". It's one of the particles you can use with あふれる, 満ちる, etc. Both ～にあふれる and ～であふれる are used, but the former tends to be used with intangible things like 笑顔, 人情味, etc.

> コウイチ様は人情味**にあふれている**すばらしいお方です。
> Mr. Koichi is a wonderful person **full of** humanity.